# PATH_INFO returns empty string wsgi/python apache

Tags: python, wsgi

I created an application using wsgi/python and was using an wsgi server and hosting on localhost. When I ported the same application to apache server, environ['PATH_INFO'] is not working and returns empty string. I also tried REQUEST_URI but no success.

**manage.py**

```
def application(environ, start_response):
path = environ.get('PATH_INFO', '')

if path == '/':
    #do some stuff
path=path.lstrip('/')
if path == 'createWS':
  return show_create_ws(environ,start_response)
if path == 'check_create_params':
  return check_create_params(environ,start_response)
```

**server_setting**

WSGIScriptAlias = /manage.py ${APOLLO_ROOT}/wsgi-scripts/manage.py

How to access the URI on apache server in wsgi/python?

Comment: What is the URL you are currently using to access to the WSGI application? Can you fix up the WSGISriptAlias directive line you quoted so matches what you are actually using as there would be no '=' in the actual line as you quote.

Comment: actually, it is a prod thing and thats how we do the setting for apache. Sorry about that. I figured out a way to do. So, I am doing request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)     d = parse_qs(request_body) and then checking the value of each button click to route accordingly.